# Create a new percent change column from 2 columns in a table in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to add a column to my table that is the calculated percent change between to columns in my table.
this is the result of the current code:
[image: table1]

I want to add a column called "% change" that calculates the percent change between column 2 and 3.

The imput CSV looks like this:
[image: input-csv]

R script sample:

```
data1 <- read_csv("table.csv")

data1$DATE <- as.Date(paste(data1$DATE,"-01",sep=""))  

maxDate <- max(data1$DATE)
minDate <- min(data1$DATE)

data1 <- data1 %>%
  select(DATE, `Traveller characteristics`, VALUE) %>%
  filter(DATE == maxDate | DATE == minDate) 

data1 <- recast(data1, `Traveller characteristics` + variable ~ DATE, id.var = c("DATE", "Traveller characteristics"))
data1 <- select(data1, -variable)
data1
```

Comment: Can you share reproducible example using dput()

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your first image, your dataframe may look like this:

```
data1 <- data.frame(Travaller = c("TC-1", "TC-2", "TC-3", "TC-4"),
                    "01/07/2019" = c(4713420, 3615631, 2398407, 979267),
                    "01/07/2020" = c(141772, 113414, 100351, 69390),
                    check.names = F)

  Travaller 01/07/2019 01/07/2020
1      TC-1    4713420     141772
2      TC-2    3615631     113414
3      TC-3    2398407     100351
4      TC-4     979267      69390
```

You can add the percentage with the `mutate` function. Either by column number or column name. Both ways show the same decrease of over 90% from 2019 to 2020.

```
data2 <- data1 %>% 
  mutate(`% change` = (data1[, 3] - data1[, 2])/data1[, 2]*100)

data3 <- data1 %>% 
  mutate(`% change` = (`01/07/2020` - `01/07/2019`)/`01/07/2019`*100)


  Travaller 01/07/2019 01/07/2020  % change
1      TC-1    4713420     141772 -96.99216
2      TC-2    3615631     113414 -96.86323
3      TC-3    2398407     100351 -95.81593
4      TC-4     979267      69390 -92.91409
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks